# Os "_id" do MongoDB são únicos entre as coleções?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql

É possível que o mesmo `ObjectId` do MongoDB seja gerado para um documento em duas coleções diferentes no mesmo banco de dados?

Comment: Queres saber se podes fazer a duplicação ou se é provavel acontecer por uma falha do sistema?

Comment: Por uma falha. Podendo criar a  regra de negócio partindo desse pressuposto (duplicidade possível ou não).

Comment: Certo! A melhor abordagem seria não considerar o pressuposto de *duplicidade*. Mesmo porque a possibilidade de isso acontecer é extremamente remota, quase que nunca vai acontecer. Acontecer isso, é o mesmo que se repetir o DateTime. Improvavel!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação oficial, ObjectIds são valores pequenos, "provavelmente" exclusivos, de geração rápida e ordenados.

Este "provavelmente" da documentação estaria mais relacionado à impossibilidade de garantir que nunca estes ids poderão se repetir, principalmente pela natureza da arquitetura do MongoDB em facilitar as bases de dados distribuídas. Porém ainda não me deparei com nenhum relato de uso que tivesse gerado uma diplicidade.

Ainda da documentação Os valores de ObjectId têm 12 bytes de comprimento, consistindo em:

- um valor de carimbo de data/hora (timestamp) de 4 bytes, representando a criação do ObjectId, medido em segundos
- um valor aleatório de 5 bytes
- um contador de incremento de 3 bytes, inicializado com um valor aleatório

Desta forma é possível verificar o por quê a composição do ObjectId torna extremamente difícil uma duplicidade, não é infalível, mas é muitíssimo raro.

A documentação ainda descreve que o formato BSON em si seja little-endian, os valores de timestamp e contador são big-endian, com os bytes mais significativos aparecendo primeiro na sequência de bytes.

Para verificar a documentação oficial [MongoDB ObjectID - BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)

Answer (score 0):

O ObjectId gera um valor único, que consiste em:

- um valor de timestamp de 4-bytes, representando o momento da criação do ObjectId.
- um valor random de 5 bytes.
- Um valor incremental, inicializado pelo valor randomico.

Mais informações em: [https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb#:~:text=ObjectID%20is%20automatically%20generated%20by,to%20sort%20by%20creation%20time](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb#:%7E:text=ObjectID%20is%20automatically%20generated%20by,to%20sort%20by%20creation%20time).

e

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/